# Iteration over a list

Tags: loops, python-3.x, iteration

i'm struggling with the following question:

*Write a function has23(nums) that takes an int list of length 2 and returns `True` if it contains a `2` or a `3`.*

Mycode:

```
def has23(nums):
    for i in nums:
        if i == 2 or i == 3:
            return True
        return False
```

Testing:

`has23([2, 5])`
Expected: `True`
Got: `True`

`has23([42, 53])`
Expected: `False`
Got: `False`

`has23([4, 3])`
Expected: `True`
Got: `**False**`

`has23([1, 2])`
Expected: `True`
Got: `**False**`

I dont know why it's returning `False` to me, when it should be `True` in the last two tests.

Comment: Apologies for the invalid rollback.

Comment: Don't need a loop: `def has23(nums): return 2 in nums or 3 in nums`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indentation is important. You're only iterating once because `return False` appears in your loop, causing it to exit early. Change it to:

```
def has23(nums):
    for i in nums:
        if i == 2 or i == 3:
            return True
    return False
```

As mentioned by @dawg, you don't need a loop.

```
def has23(nums):
    return 2 in nums or 3 in nums
```

```js
// Python interpreter courtesy of http://www.skulpt.org/
// of which I have no affiliation
function outf(text) {
    var mypre = document.getElementById("output");
    mypre.innerHTML = mypre.innerHTML + text;
}

function builtinRead(x) {
    if (Sk.builtinFiles === undefined || Sk.builtinFiles["files"][x] === undefined)
        throw "File not found: '" + x + "'";
    return Sk.builtinFiles["files"][x];
}

function runit() {
    var prog = document.getElementById("yourcode").value;
    var mypre = document.getElementById("output");
    mypre.innerHTML = '';
    Sk.canvas = "mycanvas";
    Sk.pre = "output";
    Sk.configure({
        output: outf,
        read: builtinRead
    });
    try {
        eval(Sk.importMainWithBody("<stdin>", false, prog));
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e.toString())
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/skulpt/skulpt-dist/master/skulpt.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src= "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/skulpt/skulpt-dist/master/skulpt-stdlib.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<form style='float:left; margin: 5px'>
    <textarea cols="40" id="yourcode" rows="10">def has23(nums):
        return 2 in nums or 3 in nums
print(has23([2, 5]))
print(has23([42, 53]))
print(has23([4, 3]))
print(has23([1, 2]))
    </textarea><br>
    <button onclick="runit()" type="button">Run</button>
</form>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: Or, perhaps even better, `def has_ns(li, *ns): return any(n in li for n in ns)` Then call with a variable tuple of tests: `has_ns([5,4,3], 2, 3)`